# Start a Task/Method over textbox.text. how to convert?

Tags: c#, winforms, task

I'm trying to figure out how to wrap a text from a TextBox in a start task function.

I have prepared ready tasks with very specific names. But I would like to start these tasks with priority. This means that the user should determine in 8 text boxes for himself which task should be started first and which should be started afterwards. So I need to know how to address a task via a text box.
The user should type only Numbers from 1-8 in the textboxes.

**First: i dont know really if this is all correct. This is the second time i create a Class. The First one was really easy. But to create a Priorized or for the user Custom Task Start function seems not so easy.**

My Class:

```
    internal class Priorized_Skills
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public Key A { get; set; }
    public Key B { get; set; }
    public Key C { get; set; }
    public Key D { get; set; }
    public Key E { get; set; }
    public Key F { get; set; }
    public Key G { get; set; }
    public Key H { get; set; }
    
    public async void Priorized(Key Key, ChaosBot ChaosBot)
    {
        try
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var token = cts.Token;
            var t1 = Task.Run(() => Convert.ToString(Key), token);
            await Task.WhenAny(new[] { t1 });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // Handle canceled
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Handle other exceptions
        }
        
    }
    public enum Key
    {
        A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, D = 4, E = 5, F = 6, G = 7, H = 8
    }
```

My Public:

```
Priorized_Skills SKILLS = new Priorized_Skills();
        {

            SKILLS.A = Priorized_Skills.Key.A;
            SKILLS.B = Priorized_Skills.Key.B;
            SKILLS.C = Priorized_Skills.Key.C;
            SKILLS.D = Priorized_Skills.Key.D;
            SKILLS.E = Priorized_Skills.Key.E;
            SKILLS.F = Priorized_Skills.Key.F;
            SKILLS.G = Priorized_Skills.Key.G;
            SKILLS.F = Priorized_Skills.Key.H;


        };
```

And this are the shortend function:

```
  public Priorized_Skills prioSkills;
  prioSkills.Priorized(txPQ.Text.Key);
```

Comment: it's not really clear what *Start a Task/Method over textbox.text* or *wrap a text from a TextBox in a start task function* mean. Are you trying to run Tasks using the name of a Method?

Comment: I have prepared ready tasks with very specific names. But I would like to start these tasks with priority. This means that the user should determine in 6 text boxes for himself which task should be started first and which should be started afterwards. So I need to know how to address a task via a text box

Comment: `token` is the second parameter, you're missing a comma and some brackets in the wrong place: `Task.Run(() => Convert.ToString(txPriorizeF.Text), token);`. Other than that, I'm unsure what 'addressing a task via a text box' means.

Comment: var t4 = Task.Run(() =>  HERE COMES THE NAME, and this name i want to set it over a textbox... But your comment already helped me :) thanks

Comment: You probably want a class object that contains a method delegate and a Property that allows to set the *priority* and an `ID` property. The you can use the `ID` as the associator and order a list of these class objects by priority, as determined by the association. -- I have no idea what a User writes in one of your TextBoxes and how this *selects* a method to run, clarify that.  Also, this: `var t4 = Task.Run(() => Convert.ToString(txPriorizeF.Text)(token));` doesn't make sense. The question is quite obscure.

Comment: Hey can you give a look on my edited Post? Thanks